# #define macro redefined

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, c-preprocessor

Can you help me avoid this warning: **'kFontFromFontSize' macro redefined**

in Gameconfig.h

```
#ifndef __GAME_CONFIG_H
#define __GAME_CONFIG_H

//
// Supported Autorotations:
//      None,
//      UIViewController,
//      CCDirector
//
#define kFontFromiPaoneToiPad 2.1

#define kFontFromFontSize 2*kFontFromiPaoneToiPad
```

Answer (score 0):

Your defines seems to work fine when I test using Visual Studio. Are you sure you are not defining these some other place as well? Perhaps your compiler treats it differently. In that case, you can use const globals instead:

```
const float kFontFromiPaoneToiPad = 2.1;
const float kFontFromFontSize = 2 * kFontFromiPaoneToiPad;
```

BTW, it is considered a good practice to use parenthesis around compound expressions in #define to avoid any potential problems when it is substituted in your code.

Comment: const XXX is preferable to #define for constant values anyway